# Как "подключить" к виртуалке на qemu/kvm два виртуальных диска .qcow2 ? Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm, qemu, виртуальная-машина

Есть вм с убунту на qemu/kvm. Использую Virtual Machine Manager. Есть виртуальный диск с осью: `ubuntu.qcow2`.Если я создам еще один диск (qcow2), но пустой, то как мне сделать так, чтобы виртуальная ubuntu его видела? Ну то есть к настоящему компу я могу подключить несколько дисков, то как я могу так же подключить к вм несколько виртуальных дисков?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qcow2 с той разницей, что после partprobe распознанные разделы надо просунуть в виртуальную машину и их там смонтировать.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Можете пожалуйста дать полный ответ?

Comment: Это надо QEMU ставить, какие-то образы создавать, пилить и убеждаться по шагам, что всё работает. А у вас, я так смекаю, всё уже готово :)

Comment: [`$ virsh attach`](https://www.yandex.ru/search/?text=virsh%20attach)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Пасиб ;)

Answer (score 0):

вид/подробности/ В левом нижнем углу есть кнопка - добавить оборудование